# I want to play music in a loop

Tags: python, ios, pythonista

I make music player in Pythonista. A single mp3 file plays fine, but if I play multiple mp3 files, they all play at the same time.

Anyone has any idea?

This is my code:

```
import sound
import time
import glob

fileList = glob.glob("i7/*") #my folder

playerlist = []
for file in fileList:
    filename = file 
    sound.set_honors_silent_switch(False)
    sound.set_volume(1)

    player = sound.Player(filename) 
    playerlist.append(player)

for playerMin in playerlist:
    playerMin.play() #same time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/sound.html#module-sound), `Player.play()` just "Starts playing audio." If you want to play the song successively, you'll have to wait to play a song until the previous song ends because `play` does not block the main thread until the song is done playing.

Try this:

```
import sound
import time

### Setup ###
sound.set_honors_silent_switch(False)
sound.set_volume(1)

### You populate this ###
files = [...] 

### Play songs in order ###
for filename in files:
    player = sound.Player(filename) 
    player.play()
    time.sleep(player.duration) # this is the key part –– makes the loop wait to play the next song until this song is done playing
    player.stop()
```

This method is super flexible. For example, if you wanted to fade between songs you could ramp the volume while making the loop `sleep` for a little less than the song duration. That gets more complicated, but it's fundamentally done like this.